# postfix aliases: is it possible to specify one alias for a class of emails?

Tags: centos, postfix

I'm configuring postfix on centos. some action is to be done when email recieved on dosomeaction_id@my.domain.com. Is it necessary to specify an alias (it's always the same sh script) for each id or I can somehow specify it one time for all emails of class dosomeaction_id@my.domain.com?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could do that once time is using regex but for security reasons regex are not allowed in the aliases and virtual user table. http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html